# Taking one element from both list if they are not the same/taking specific 2 elements from one list

Tags: list, haskell

I have two lists that contain this datatype:

```
data Student = Student {firstName::String, lastName::String, age::Int}
   deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

I need to make another list that will have unique elements from both of this list.
Ideally this list would contain only firstNames as they can only differ in this one field firstName.

I sort of solved, my solution goes like this:

```
listOfChanges :: [Student] -> [Student] -> [String]
listOfChanges list1 list2 =
                let c = intersect list1 list2
                    b = union list1 list2
                in  listEvent(nSame b c)

nSame (x:xs) ys = if x `elem` ys
                 then nSame xs ys
                 else x:nSame xs (delete x ys)
nSame [] _ = []
nSame _ [] = []

extractName::Student -> String
extractName (Student firstName _ _) = firstName

listEvent :: [Student] -> [String]
listEvent list = map extractName list
```

But I would like to convert final list to list of type:

```
data StudentsFirstNameChangeEvent = StudentsFirstNameChangeEvent {oldName::String, newNames::String}
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

My final list:

```
["Alicja","Batrek","Damian","AlicjaX","BatrekX","DamianX"]
```

"Alicja","Batrek","Damian" - oldNames.
"AlicjaX","BatrekX","DamianX" - newNames.

When it actually should be:

```
[StudentsFirstNameChangeEvent {oldName = "Alicja", newName = "Alicjax"},StudentsFirstNameChangeEvent {oldName = "Bartek", newName = "Bartekx"}, ...]
enter code here
```

I think im done with haskell, but this is my final progress:

```
correctSplit :: [String] -> [[String]]
correctSplit list = 
              let x = length list
                  x1 = (x `div` 2)
              in splitEvery x1 list

splitEvery _ [] = []
splitEvery n list = first : (splitEvery n rest)
  where
    (first,rest) = splitAt n list

proList :: [Student] -> [Student] -> [String]
proList list1 list2 =
              let x = listOfChanges list1 list2
                  x2 = correctSplit x
                  x3 = x2 !! 0
                  x4 = x2 !! 1
              in merge x3 x4


merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs     []     = xs
merge []     ys     = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys
```

And the final list is now:

```
["Alicja","AlicjaX","Batrek","BatrekX","Damian","DamianX"]
```

But I still have no idea how to convert either of those list into the type I need.

Well and it turns out that correct way to process this is much shorter:

```
listOfChanges :: [Student] -> [Student] -> [StudentsFirstNameChangeEvent]
listOfChanges list1 list2 =
                    let mask = intersect list1 list2
                        x1 = list1 \\ mask
                        x2 = list2 \\ mask
                    in changeList x1 x2


changeList :: [Student] -> [Student] -> [StudentsFirstNameChangeEvent]
changeList a b = zipWith StudentsFirstNameChangeEvent (map                   firstName a) (map firstName b)
```

Comment: Have you learned about `let` or `where`? They should let you move those intermediate definitions into a local scope.

Comment: Please do not put code in the comment section.

Comment: let syntax stuff is in use now, as it should.

Comment: Your `nSame` function doesn’t make sense to me. It seems to be equivalent to `(\\)`. The `delete` expression won’t do anything: it occurs in the branch where you’ve already determined that `x` is not in `ys`

Comment: Can you give some simple examples of what the inputs and corresponding outputs should be? At the moment it seems like you can do `\ a b -> zipWith StudentsFirstNameChangeEvent (map firstName a) (map firstName b)`.

Comment: yep your solution almost does the job, but it takes every record, not just the one that are different.

Comment: yep nSame is exactly the same as (\\), but I didn't realize that something like (\\) should already exist.

Comment: Oh right, I solved this in console thanks to your function and this (\\) operator